# Using command output as argument to another command

Tags: command-line

Cannot figure out how to use the output of :pwd as argument to :helptags. Something like:

```
:helptags . exec ':pwd'
```

Tried many combinations of |, :exec, :call and ! .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Backticks can be used many places, so:

```
:helptags `pwd`
```

will do what you want, although so will:

```
:helptags .
```

Other uses would be things like:

```
:e `date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`
```

which edits a file whose name is the current date in the format YYYY-MM-DD (the backslashes are because % is a special character there).